# Cycle drawing with nodes from a list

Tags: tikz-pgf

Credits for the code beloow goes to Jerome Tremblay and original code can be found [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/)

```
% A simple cycle
% Author : Jerome Tremblay
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s$};
  \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It all works perfectly until I would like to use another nodes, for example from this list

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}
```

which should be typsetted rather than numerical ordered nodes. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \def \n {9}
        \def \radius {3cm}
        \def \margin {8} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

        \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
        {    
            \draw[->, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
                arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
        }

       \foreach \t [count=\i] in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i} 
       {
       \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\i - 1)}:\radius) {\t};
       }

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives[image]